# How do I do a not exists query for an attribute in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have objects with dynamic fields in Elasticsearch that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "fields": [
    {
      "identifier": "product",
      "value": "Google Home"
    },
    {
      "identifer": "currency",
      "value": "bitcoin"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "fields": [
    {
      "identifier": "product",
      "value": "Alexa"
    },
    {
      "identifer": "currency",
      "value": "INR"
    }
  ]
},
{
   "_id": 3,
  "fields": [
    {
      "identifer": "currency",
      "value": "USD"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I write a query that will fetch the objects that DO NOT have a certain field value, i.e. I want to be able to search for all records that don't have a specific product associated with them.
Let's say I want to search all items that don't have the product "Google Home". It should return only the 2nd and 3rd items.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need for that.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fields.value": "Google Home"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Further Read about filters [es Filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: Apologies, I realized I hadn't quite put in my entire requirement. Updated the question - this will not allow me to match where NOT a certain product.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer against your updated Question please check now.

Comment: This won't give me the right answer as I need to search all items where product is not google home i.e. the 2nd and 3rd item. Your answer will only give me the 3rd.

Comment: @hash12 PLease check now it is updated according to your requirement if you want to skip any product just use value attribute of the source field and you will not have that data due to using must_not

Comment: This will also match any other fields that may have the value "Google Home". I would want to scope it to only those where the identifier is "product".

Comment: For that you have to add one more match block in there to make it like AND condition right now I’m from mobile will update ans later